# How can I write a linq query to get blogId in mvc web application

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have 2 models :

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string RealBlogId { get; set; }     
}

  public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int? ReadingNumber { get; set; }
    public string RealPostId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishedTime { get; set; }    
}
```

I want to write a function in PostController that returns me RealBlogId 
using postId

```
 public class PostController : Controller
  {
     private ReaderDb db = new ReaderDb();

     public ActionResult Details(int? postId)
     {
        if (postId == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Post post = db.Posts.Find(postId);
        if (post == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
            IQueryable<string>realPostId = from r in db.Posts 
            where r.Id == id   //This query gives me realPostId
            select r.RealId;

          //second query

 }
```

}

And How can i write a query that returnsme realBlogId in second query

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it:

```
var query = from post in db.Posts
            from blog in db.Blogs
            where post.BlogId == blog.Id && post.Id == postId
            select blog.RealBlogId;

var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

A better approach is to modify your models so that you make the relationship between them explicit like this:

```
public class Blog
{
    public Blog()
    {
        Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    //Rest of properties here
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? BlogId { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
    //Reset of properties here

}
```

This will allow you to create queries like this:

```
var result = db.Posts
    .Where(x => x.Id == postId)
    .Select(x => x.Blog.RealBlogId) //Notice how we reference Post.Blog here
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with this LINQ query

```
var realBlogId = (from post in db.Posts
                  join blog in db.Blogs on post.BlogId equals blog.Id
                  where post.Id == postId
                  select blog.RealBlogId)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or using lambda

```
var realBlogId = db.Posts.Where(p => p.Id == postId)
                         .Join(db.Blogs, p => p.BlogId, b => b.Id, (p, b) => b.RealBlogId)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code shoud work.

```
db.Blogs.Where(blog => 
       db.Posts.Where(post => post.Id == postId)
             .Any(post => post.BlogId == blog.Id));
```

We are selecting every blog is referenced by any post with specific id.